# Getting the pci device no (B:D:F) for DRAM Controller from linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, firmware, pci

I am developing a linux kernel module that will check few things in DRAM controller's pci configuration space. For that I am going to use `pci_get_device()` and `pci_read_config_*`.

But before that I need to know the B:D:F or Vendor id/device id of DRAM controller.
So, is there any way to find that or I have hardcode the value (by consulting the datasheet) in the module?

I know `lspci` output show that detail, so it must be possible.

```
 lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
...
```

Comment: By "B:D:F" I guess you mean the bus:device:function numbers. Those describe the address of a PCI function within the system (or rather, within a PCI "domain"), although in Linux the bus numbers are assigned dynamically, so are somewhat arbitrary. Those numbers have nothing to do with the Vendor ID and Device ID (plus Subvendor ID and Subdevice ID) that indicate what the device actually _is_, rather than its location. It is common to hard code the Vendor ID and Device ID (and sub-IDs) and/or the PCI class code, but it is not common to hard code the bus:device:function numbers.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What I understand is, I have to hardcode the vendor id and device id of DRAM controller for each processor.